# Using different sized images on carousel in bootstrap for different device sizes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I don't know what the best practice would be to solve my problem. I'm making a webpage with a large edge-to edge carousel that sits below the navbar and looks great on desktops with a 1:3 ratio image size. On mobile, it looks too small and thin so I made a new set of images with a 2:3 ratio size I want to display on smaller screens in my carousel.

How should I go about doing this? Javascript to change the images on different sizes? Hidden columns for the carousel on different port sizes with one for mobile and one for desktop? I just need to know the way that makes most sense/best practices to solve this problem.

My carousel HTML for point of reference:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <!--<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>   optional   -->
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="first-slide" src="img/carousel/carousel1.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="second-slide" src="img/carousel/carousel2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="third-slide" src="img/carousel/carousel3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: You're going to want to use CSS media queries to do this. You can use it to read the screen size and set the style accordingly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: i don't know that i can make it work with media queries since i plan to change the actual source of the images. the files i want to display in 2:3 are different than those on desktop at 1:3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using **@MediaQueries**.

You create two different carousels in the **HTML** and define which one to display using media queries. You can customize the **CSS** for each carousel individually to get the sizing correct.

[Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/FWV7s5J90v#) - Change the width of the window to below / above 1000px to see it update.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span8">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide wide">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://ecowatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Tiger.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://ecowatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Tiger.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://ecowatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Tiger.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
    <div id="myCarouselNarrow" class="carousel slide narrow">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarouselNarrow" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarouselNarrow" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarouselNarrow" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://img1.rnkr-static.com/list_img_v2/5795/1825795/C480/best-of-awwducational-fun-facts-about-adorable-animals-u1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="http://img1.rnkr-static.com/list_img_v2/5795/1825795/C480/best-of-awwducational-fun-facts-about-adorable-animals-u1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="http://img1.rnkr-static.com/list_img_v2/5795/1825795/C480/best-of-awwducational-fun-facts-about-adorable-animals-u1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarouselNarrow" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarouselNarrow" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wide {
  width: 600px;
}

.narrow {
  width: 480px;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .wide {
    display: none;
  }
  .narrow {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this load all the images directly?